# Espresso UI test ignore onKeyPress Event Callback for React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-espresso

I am trying to write Espresso UI tests for android, the app is built with react native, it's a secret Input component that can take digits as input and everything works fine manually, however on testing, for some reasons `onKeyPress` even callbacks are ignored and the UI test can't be written further for the same reason.

on Manually using the component on the Simulator it works as expected the callback does fires, but on espresso Automated tests it does not.

To confirm the `onkeyPress` event does trigger callbacks when the native softKeyboard of the android device is Used, what can be reason behind this?

[image]

Tried running the Test but no expected outcomes, though the `onChangeText` method does work, so seems weird am i doing something wrong.